# com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: Error reading string at file pointer

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Getting below exception while reading a PDF. It opens well in Acrobat reader. I read in another question that though its opened in acrobat its not necessary to open via iText because PDF contains an error and he recommends to fix the PDF. But the file is coming from the client and they are able to open Acrobat, so either I have to fix it or show the error or warning in Acrobat.

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: Error reading string at file pointer 10891; Original message: Error reading string at file pointer 10891
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:655)
```

Excerpt of PDF file

```
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Developer 2000)
/CreatorDate (
/Author (Oracle Reports)
/Producer (Oracle PDF driver)
/Title (con5010I412014141258.pdf)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids 4 0 R
/Count 5 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Length 8 0 R>>
stream
BT
```

1. Is there any way I can show the client that the PDF has error? either via Acrobat or some other software rather Java exception.
2. Is there way to go around this error and proceed? We faced similar issues for secured PDF and we did unlock. Please suggest

Comment: If possible, please share the PDF. If not, at least share a small except sound offset 10891.

Comment: Sorry It's confidential. Is there anyway to take offset ?

Comment: I meant a small "excerpt around"... Smart phone keyboards... Sigh

Comment: Seems that you are using iText 5 or higher, meaning that your customer is probably also a customer of iText Software (if not, all the source code using iText must be disclosed to be compliant with the AGPL). Ask your customer to share the document with iText Software the same way he shared the document with you. He can use his customer login to create a ticket in our closed (confidential) ticketing system. As soon as we receive the document, we'll take a look.

Comment: We are using iText 5.4.4. The document is uploaded by user in client's online system and we are receiving it to process it. Unfortunately we are not allowed to share the document in iText. Sorry about that. Is there any other way I can debug it or ignore the error and process it. If I use 5.4.3 I'm not getting this error. Is there any other problem will I face it

Comment: One thing I noticed in all the files that it has %PDF-1.1 in the first line, normal PDF has %PDF1.5 or %PDF1.4. Is it related to this one?

Comment: Just Noticed the PDF header details, Creator Date doesn't have close bracket. So PDF is invalid I will ask the client to correct at their side. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually a Invalid PDF. When I open the PDF in text editor I noticed that header has CreatorDate with out close bracket. I just added the close bracket with valid date like this CreatorDate (05 November 2014 17:50:24) then It works. I asked client to correct on their side

Comment: found to be the same issue in my case as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Edit the PDF in a text editor (notepad, notepad++, etc.) and simply add a closing parenthesis.

So the following line:
/CreatorDate (

Changes to:
/CreatorDate ()

Comment: "Editing" a PDF in a text editor more often than not damages PDFs.

Comment: Not necessarily. The old Oracle tools (Developer 2000) created PDFs with the malformed "/CreatorDate ( " line in the PDF. I've personally used notepad++ to edit thousands of PDFs to resolve the issue.

Comment: I said "more often than not" which implies "Not necessarily". That been said, though: I hope you also correct cross reference tables or streams whenever you add or remove some byte(s): If you don't, you'll most likely render them incorrect which makes the PDF a damaged one; even if some PDF viewers may show the PDF as desired, the PDF still is damaged which may give rise to funny effects when being processed further.

Comment: Is a  common problem with oracle reports, adding ) programatically, solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it allows me to use printing to fix the file.

(The printed file is basically a binary/image of the file, lots of info/metadata is lost)

[image]